# Confusing EcmaScript Specification - Declaration Binding Instantiation

Tags: javascript, hoisting, ecma

When I read specification for learn "hoisting" in there **FunctionDeclaration** happens on *step 5* but **VariableDeclaration** happened *step 8* and I think this mean **function declaration** are given higher priority than **variable declaration**. 
 
What do you think why Function Declaration declare fist and is this have any reason?

Note: You can read this part from this link http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5

I have hypothesis for my question. This is not answer this is hypothesis because I don't really know this question answer apparently people also don't know answer. 
 
My hypothesis this 
Function can override another function but variable can't I think because that first functionDeclaration happens.

Comment: I'll just note that v5.1 is **very** out of date, having been superceded by ES2015 ES2016, ES2017, ES2018, and ES2019. If you want to study the JavaScript specification, I suggest the [living specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/).

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking here. Yes, Step 5 creates bindings before Step 8 would (in that spec's language). But...what is it you're asking about that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I ask any reason for this?

Comment: Because there has to be an order to things...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for link. I read from new link but I don't think Declaration Binding Instantiation change in new spesification )))

Comment: Okay why order not happened backwards. For example why VariableDeclaration not happened before FunctionDeclaration?

Comment: "Why does language X have feature Y" questions are ultimately best answered by the language designers.

Comment: Okay I search any langugae designer here )) Do you reccomend any site for contact   language designers? :d

Comment: @MuradSofiyev - His name is Brendan Eich, and he's reasonably responsive on Twitter, but not on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Scott Marcus It's not necessarily that  he is asking "how to scream into the wind". Sometimes  you want to know why white color is white, and there is nothing wrong with that. Everything has it's explanation, even why white color is white.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would explain how you would use the information (the reason for the behavior) if you had it right now.

Comment: I agree with @Noob. People must ask question not only read rules. If any rule have this is meaning this rule have any reason. If one rule have without reason this rule false.

Comment: @Noob Agreed. **But the question has been asked and answered** and yet the OP persists, thus screaming into the wind.

Comment: This question not answered fully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two choices, either this code is invalid (e.g., syntax error):

```js
function foo() {
    console.log("foo1");
}
var foo = function() {
    console.log("foo2");
};
foo();
```

...or there is an order to things. In the JavaScript spec, in this case, there's an order to things:

1. The function declaration creates a binding in the scope for `foo` which logs `foo1`.
2. The `var` in `var foo = ...` has no effect because *varAlreadyDeclared* is true.
3. `foo` is overwritten with the value resulting from the function expression `foo = function() { /*...*/ };`

Why? Because that's how it's specified. More specifically, because a function declaration and a `var` statement both create a *mutable binding* in the execution context, so whichever one gets there first creates the binding. "First" again needs definition, and so the definition chosen was that the declaration creates the binding first. But both create mutable bindings, and remember that the `var foo` part and the `foo = ...` part are handled completely separately. Since function declarations are processed before the step-by-step execution of the code, the following does exactly the same thing as the above:

```js
var foo = function() {
    console.log("foo2");
};
function foo() {
    console.log("foo1");
}
foo();
```

Although the function declaration creates the binding first and sets it to the function that does `console.log("foo1")`, the `foo = ...` part happens afterward and updates the binding so that it refers to the new function that does `console.log("foo2")`.

Other choices were available to Brendan Eich, but this was the choice he made during those fateful 10 days in May, 1995. :-) And it *does* follow logically from these decisions:

1. Function declarations create mutable bindings
2. Function declarations and `var` declarations create the *same kind* of bindings
3. Function declarations are hoisted (e.g., the function is created and assigned to the binding before step-by-step execution begins)
4. The *declaration* part of a `var` is hoisted, using the initialization value `undefined`, but the *initializer* part of `var x = y` is not set until the step-by-step execution of the code.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how Mr Eich crammed all the little decisions like this into such a short period of time.

Comment: @Pointy - It's amazing what you can do when you throw caution to the wind. Some of this, I suspect, was justified/codified after-the-fact based on what the initial implementation ended up doing almost as a side-effect of Getting It Done. :-)

Comment: Okay let's think different. For example this process can happened by source code order also.

Comment: But you say this is Bendan's choice and we can't do anything yeah?

Comment: @MuradSofiyev changing something like this would destroy the Internet because there are countless billions of lines of existing JavaScript code that might be affected.

Comment: @MuradSofiyev - *"this process can happened by source code order also"* It could, but it doesn't. Function declarations are hoisted. *"you say this is Bendan's choice and we can't do anything yeah"* I have no idea what you mean by "do anything." The language is specified by a specification. That spec has had lots of inputs. One of them (a pretty big one) is what Brendan did in May 1995. Since then, backward-compatibility has been a pretty big deal.

Comment: Okay is this meaning this is not have any reason for ordering this is Brendan's choice. We don't have more information about that. I understand true?

Comment: @MuradSofiyev - As I said, it flows from other decisions that, taken as a whole, make sense. But yes, every once in a while, it is just "because that's the way it is." :-) (I don't think that's true in this particular case, but...)

Comment: Cool I understand what you mean. I approve this answer true but this is not meaning specification not true :d

Comment: @MuradSofiyev The same exact result could have been achieved by saying that `var` bindings are created first and then `function` bindings overwrite their values. Doesn't make any difference to the code.

Comment: @Bergi But some example ordering important

Answer (score 1):

Both function declarations and variable declarations are *hoisted*.

Functions are *hoisted* first, and then variables.

```
foo(); // 1

var foo;

function foo() {
  console.log(1);
}

foo = function() {
  console.log(2);
};
```

Notice that `var foo` was the duplicate (and thus ignored) declaration, even though it came before the function declaration.

Also, an interesting fact that subsequent function declarations do override previous ones.

```
foo(); // 3

function foo() {
  console.log(1);
}

var foo = function() {
  console.log(2);
};

function foo() {
  console.log(3);
}
```

More information you can find in the [You Don't Know JS: Scope & Closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch4.md) book

Comment: I know function declaration happened first but this is interesting for me that is reason . Also I read YDKJS and I ask this question to @gettify  
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/issues/1501

Comment: I upvote your comment because you give me idea :) Function can override itself but variable not I think this is important point for ordering

Comment: @MuradSofiyev It also makes sense to note that `var a = 11;` is basically two statements: `var a;` (declaration) and `a = 11` (assignment). Only the declarations are hoisted, while assignments are left in place.

Comment: Yeah that's true